# Socket listener reacts only once

Tags: c#, .net, sockets

My socket listens the port, but reacts on message only first time and never more.
What's wrong? Any suggestions how to fix it? 'Cause I already don't know what to do. Maybe the way I listening the port is not appropriate?

```
public partial class Listener
{
    private void InitListener()
    {
        Logger.InitializeLogger();
        var listenSocket = new Socket(AddressFamily.InterNetwork,
                                         SocketType.Stream,
                                         ProtocolType.Tcp);
        var ipHostInfo = Dns.Resolve(Dns.GetHostName());
        var ipAddress = ipHostInfo.AddressList[0];
        var endPoint = new IPEndPoint(ipAddress, Settings.Default.Port);
        listenSocket.Bind(endPoint);
        listenSocket.Listen(Settings.Default.listenerMaxConnection);
        Logger.EventLogItem.WriteEntry(
            $"Listen to {ipAddress}:{Settings.Default.Port}");


        Logger.EventLogItem.WriteEntry("Connection Recieved");

        Thread thread = new Thread(o => Listen(listenSocket));
        thread.Start();

    }

    public void Listen(Socket socket)
    {
        var directory = @"C:\\Users\\*****\\Desktop\\bat files";
        var handler = socket.Accept();
        while (true)
        {
            try
            {
                while (handler.Connected)
                {
                    byte[] x = new byte[100000];
                    handler.Receive(x);
                    var command = new string(Encoding.UTF8.GetChars(x.Where(t => t != 0).ToArray()));
                    if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(command))
                    {
                        Logger.EventLogItem.WriteEntry("Warning: Empty string");
                        break;
                    }
                    Logger.EventLogItem.WriteEntry(command);
                    Console.WriteLine(command);
                    switch (command)
                    {
                        case "run":
                            var myFiles = Directory.GetFiles(directory, "*.bat");
                            foreach (var bat in myFiles)
                            {
                                Process.Start(bat);
                            }
                            Logger.EventLogItem.WriteEntry("By command: " + command +
                                                           " was executed an appropriate .bat file.");
                            break;
                        case "getThreads":
                            Logger.EventLogItem.WriteEntry("By command: " + command +
                                                           " was executed an appropriate .bat file.");
                            break;
                        case "stop":
                            Logger.EventLogItem.WriteEntry("By command: " + command +
                                                           " was executed an appropriate .bat file.");
                            break;
                        case "start":
                            Logger.EventLogItem.WriteEntry("By command: " + command +
                                                           " was executed an appropriate .bat file.");
                            break;
                        case "close":
                            Logger.EventLogItem.WriteEntry("By command: " + command +
                                                           " was executed an appropriate .bat file.");
                            break;
                    }
                }
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                Logger.EventLogItem.WriteEntry(
                    $"Exception happened in Listener: {ex.Message} - {ex.StackTrace}");
            }
        }
    }
    }

public partial class Listener
{
    public static Listener Handler { get; } = new Listener();

    public Listener()
    {
        var thread = new Thread(InitListener);
        thread.Start();
    }
}
```

And here is my main

```
 Listener listener = Listener.Handler;
```

Comment: You accepted outside the loop, so it never returns to try for the next connections

Comment: How does your client connect to the server? If it sends data and disconnects, you will need to move [`Socket.Accept`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.sockets.socket.accept(v=vs.110).aspx) into the loop. See an [example on msdn](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/6y0e13d3(v=vs.110).aspx)

Comment: @BugFinder thanks!! I didn't see that each time

Comment: @slawekwin yes, thanks! that was the problem

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your problem lies here:

```
var handler = socket.Accept();
while (true)
{
    try
    {
        while (handler.Connected)
```

As your code never leaves the while loop - it never goes round to accept the next connection.